# Community logged in user info for extraprechatform

Tags: pre-chat, snap-ins, embedded

I have implemented snap-ins (embedded chat) on Portal (VF page) and on websites, where in I am not having prechat form at all. When user clicks on "chat with an expert" button it will not goto prechat form but directly takes the chat to agent.

This helps in reducing the number of clicks the user need to make while he tries chat (prechat form will not be displayed in turn user won’t be needing to click on “start chat” button again), as well as, since user is already logged in to portal vf page or product web page, why again we would show the prechat form with user details to verify and start chat.
This I implemented by removing prechat form from snap-ins deployment and sending prechat form details to agent directly using below code snippet on portal VF page .

```
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
    "label": "First Name",
    "value": "{!portalUser.Contact.Firstname}",
    "displayToAgent": true
}, {
    "label": "Last Name",
    "value": "{!portalUser.Contact.LastName}",
    "displayToAgent": true
}, {
    "label": "Email",
    "value": "{!portalUser.Contact.Email}",
    "displayToAgent": true
}];
```

similarly when I try doing on community, I am unable to achieve this by using snippet file as below:

```
window._snapinsSnippetSettingsFile = (function() {
    console.log("Snippet settings file loaded.");
    embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
        "label":"First Name", 
        "value": "Pallavi",
        "displayToAgent":true
    },{
        "label":"Last Name", 
        "value": "Rajmohan",
        "displayToAgent":true
    },{
        "label":"Email", 
        "value": "prajmohan@test.com",
        "displayToAgent":true
    }];
})();
```

How can I get community logged in user info?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this ?

Comment: Did any one was able to get the user info on portal ?